# Strange python behavior with saving output to txt

Tags: python

It should be very simple to save the results of my program to a .txt file, however when I do this several strange things happen. First, while it only takes a few seconds for the terminal to print my results, it takes several minutes for my results to write to the .txt file. Also, when I open the text file, it does not properly save all of the information that was printed on the shell! Instead of my full results, I get "54313806']" as the first line and then only the last bit of my results save to the text file underneath that. My results are displaying properly in the terminal.

I checked other inquiries to find out how to save the results in a text file, so this is what I have:

```
with open("output.txt", "w+") as output:
     subprocess.call["python", "./my_program.py"], stdout=output)
```

Any idea on what is happening? Or should I just try to find a different way to save my output to a text file?

Here is my full code:

```
import re
import subprocess
f = open('my_program.py')

raw = f.read()
raw = raw.lower()
l = raw.splitlines()
l = [re.sub(r'\t', ' ', l) for l in l]

kiwis = []
for elem in l:
    kiwis.append(elem.strip().split(' '))
for kiwis in kiwis:
    data = kiwis[0:3] #extracting first three elements from every line
    print data

with open("output.txt", "w+") as output:
     subprocess.call["python", "./my_program.py"], stdout=output)
```

Comment: Could to add a few lines from your input file to your question, so we can see what you are trying to process?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to be recursively calling your program from inside itself like this ... you're probably spawning infinite subprocesses. I would forget the `subprocess` bit and simply write to a file like this:

```
with open("output.txt", "w+") as output:
   kiwis = []
   for elem in l:
       kiwis.append(elem.strip().split(' '))
   for kiwis in kiwis:
       data = kiwis[0:3] #extracting first three elements from every line
       output.write(data)
```

Comment: No syntax error when I try this, but it doesn't actually print anything onto my output.txt. It just leaves it empty. But all of the correct information still prints in the terminal.

Comment: did you change your print statement to an output.write?

Comment: I changed it to "output.write(data)" and got no results. But when I added "print" before that, I got the error "expected a character buffer object". I'm still new to programming so I need to figure out exactly what this error means.